# Is it possible to use an Entitlements.plist without signing the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, entitlements

I want to suppress the Photos authorization dialog when running tests in the iOS Simulator. To do so I am including an Entitlements.plist [as mentioned here](https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/276#issuecomment-30074325).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.private.tcc.allow.overridable</key>
    <array>
        <string>kTCCServiceAddressBook</string>
        <string>kTCCServiceCalendar</string>
        <string>kTCCServicePhotos</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This work fine locally when I sign the app with my developer certificate. However, I want to run these tests on CI (Travis CI, specifically) without having to upload the certificate. When I don't sign the app Xcode is nice enough to give me the following warning:

> Warning: Capabilities that require entitlements from "Supporting Files/Entitlements.plist" may not function in the Simulator because the target "Test Host" doesn't have a valid Code Signing Identity for iOS.

Is it possible to use these entitlements without signing the app?

[image: Warning screenshot]

Comment: Nope, I am still running into this problem on Xcode 6. I have not, however, tried Xcode 7 yet.